# zipfile write dont find files in gcloud

Tags: python, django, gcloud, python-zipfile

Im trying zip a few files from Google Storage.

The zipfile of Python doesnt find the files in gcloud, just in the project.

How can I do for my code find the files in gcloud?

```
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
        for revenue in revenues:
        # queryset with files a lot, so, for a each file, add in zip
            t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
            t.write(revenue.revenue.name)
            if revenue.revenue.name:
                t.seek(0)
                with default_storage.open(revenue.revenue.name, "r") as file_data:
                    zip_file.write(file_data.name, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                    # the code dont pass from this part
                t.close()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_zip.zip'
    response.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
    return response
```

In this part, I write the file that I opened from gcloud, but stop inside the function:

```
def write(self, filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None):
    """Put the bytes from filename into the archive under the name
    arcname."""
    if not self.fp:
        raise RuntimeError(
              "Attempt to write to ZIP archive that was already closed")
    st = os.stat(filename) 
    # when I try find the file, the command os.stat search in project, not in gcloud
```

the "os.stat(filename)" search for a file in project, how can I do for find in the gcloud?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by _for my code find the files in gcloud?_ There isn't much code to work with here.

Comment: The code search for the files in project tree, but I need that search in gcloud

Comment: Could you, please, be more explicit ? Do you have some files saved in a Cloud Storage bucket and you want to access them? Do you have the files saved in Cloud Shell and you want to access them ? Or are you using Cloud SDK on you personal computer and you want to get some files?

Comment: The first option. I have files saved in gcloud bucket, I can read then, what I cannot is zip then. I read the files normally, but when I'll zip that, the "zipfile" native of Python doesn't find the file in gcloud in your native process, cause it's searching into the project, not in gcloud.

Answer (score 0):

I will post my findings as an answer, since I would like to comment about few things.

I have understood:

1. You have a Python library `zipfile` that is used to work with ZIP files.
2. You are looking for files locally and add one by one into the ZIP file.
3. You would like to do this as well for files located in **Google Cloud Storage** bucket. But it is failing to find the files.

If I have misunderstood the use-case scenario, please elaborate further in a comment.

However, if this is exactly what you are trying to do, then this is not supported. In the [StackOverflow Question - Compress files saved in Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858998/4037220), it is stated that compressing files that are already in the **Google Cloud Storage** is not possible. The solution in that question is to subscribe to newly created files and then download them locally, compress them and overwrite them in GCS. As you can see, you can list the files, or iterate through the files stored in GCS, but you first need to download them to be able to process them.

**Work around**

Therefore, in your use-case scenario, I would recommend the following workaround, by using the Python client API:

1. You can use [Listing objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) Python API, to get all the objects from GCS.
2. Then you can use [Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) Python API, to download the objects locally.
3. As soon as the objects are located in local directory, you can use the `zipfile` Python library to ZIP them together, as you are already doing it.
4. Then the objects are ZIPed and if you no longer need the downloaded objects, you can delete them with `os.remove("downloaded_file.txt")`.
5. In case you need to have the compressed ZIP file in the **Google Cloud Storage** bucket, then you can use the [Uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) Python API to upload the ZIP file in the GCS bucket.

As I have mentioned above, processing files *(e.g. Adding them to a ZIP files etc.)* directly in **Google Cloud Storage** bucket, is not supported. You first need to download them locally in order to do so. I hope that my workaround is going to be helpful to you.

**UPDATE**

As I have mentioned above, zipping files while they are in GCS bucket is not supported. Therefore I have prepared for you a [working example](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Google%20Cloud%20Storage/python/dowload_zip_delete_temp_files_from_gcs.py) in Python on how to use the workaround.

> NOTE: As I am not professional on operating os commands with Python
>   library and I am not familiar with `zipfile` library, there is
>   probably a better and more efficient way of achieving this. However,
>   the code that can be found in [this GitHub link](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Google%20Cloud%20Storage/python/dowload_zip_delete_temp_files_from_gcs.py), does the following
>   procedures:

- Under `#Public variables:` section change `BUCKET_NAME` to your corresponding bucket name and execute the python script in **Google Cloud Shell**. [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/)
- Now my bucket structure is as follows:

```
gs://my-bucket/test.txt
gs://my-bucket/test1.txt
gs://my-bucket/test2.txt
gs://my-bucket/directory/test4.txt
```

When executing the command, what the app does is the following:

1. Will get the path of where the script is executed. e.g. `/home/username/myapp`.
2. It will create a temporary directory within this directory e.g. `/home/username/myapp/temp`
3. It will iterate through all the files located in the bucket that you have specified and will download them locally inside that temp directory.

   > NOTE: If the file in the bucket is under directory it will simple download the file, instead of creating that sub-directory again. You can modify the code to make it work as you desired later.
4. So the new downloaded files will look like this:

```
/home/username/myapp/temp/test.txt
/home/username/myapp/temp/test1.txt
/home/username/myapp/temp/test2.txt
/home/username/myapp/temp/test4.txt
```

5. After that, the code will zip all those files to a new `zipedFile.zip` that will be located in the same directory with the `main.py` script that you have executed.
6. When this step is done as well, the script will delete the directory `/home/username/myapp/temp/` with all of its contents.

As I have mentioned above, after executing the script locally, you should be able to see the `main.py` and an `zipedFile.zip` file with all the zipped files from the GCS bucket. Now you can take the idea of implementation and modify it according to your project's needs.

Comment: Tks man!! Your help was very useful!! So, even I can download it from GCS without difficult, I cannot compress it? For that, I need download it in my project and then compreess all, right? That's the only option? I cannot do like that, if I can my project will have a lot files in your structure.

The ideia is the same when I normally download a file. I opened a file in GCS and to write it in HttpResponse returned. I read it normally, my variable was a file, but when I used it for to write in ZipFile, the library search again for the file in my project (now came your help).

Comment: In case I missed anything or misunderstood please rephrase. 1. You can compress it but locally, not while the file is in GCS. 2. Yes you need to first download it. 3. At the moment this is the only option. 4. You can download all the files to be compressed in a custom local directory. Compress them and then delete them as soon as you are done with the compression. So you will always end up with the ZIPed file instead also with all the downloaded ones.

Comment: I tried to do that and I cannot download it in my project, I tried to save then in a directory in the project tree. How can I do?

Comment: Tks again for all help!!

Comment: Hello, Please see my UPDATED section in the answer. I have provided a working code that if you execute it in Cloud Shell it will do exactly what the workaround specified. You can take the basic implementation and modify the code according to your project's needs.

Answer (score 0):

the final code:

```
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
base_path = '/home/everton/compressedfiles/'
fiscal_compentecy_month = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), 1)
revenues = CompanyRevenue.objects.filter(company__pk=company_id, fiscal_compentecy_month=fiscal_compentecy_month)

if revenues.count() > 0:
    path = base_path + str(revenues.first().company.user.pk) + "/"
    zip_name = "{}-{}-{}-{}".format(revenues.first().company.external_id, revenues.first().company.external_name, month, year)

    for revenue in revenues:
        filename = revenue.revenue.name.split('revenues/')[1]
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        with open(path + filename, 'wb+') as file:
            file.write(revenue.revenue.read())
        file.close()

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            zip_file.write(path + file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zip_file.close()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.zip'.format(zip_name)
    response.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
    shutil.rmtree(path)
    return response
```